# Filtering not active on click using pipe

Tags: json, angular, typescript, pipe

I want to get the right products by choosing filter [myfilters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMEhL.png). This is not happens from using

store html:

```
<h2>store</h2>
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let g of GenderFilter">{{g.DisplayText}}</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let p of PriceFilter">{{p.DisplayText}}</option>
</select>

<tr *ngFor="let P of products | filer : p | orderBy: 'PriceFilter'">
  <td>{{p.DisplayText}}</td>
</tr>
```

filter pipe:

```
export class FilerPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], term): any {
    console.log('term', term);

    return term 
        ? items.filter(item => item.ProductTags.indexOf(term) !== -1)
        : items;
  }
}
```

order by pipe:

```
transform(items: Array<string>, orderBy: string): Array<string> {
  if (items !== undefined) {
    items.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[orderBy] < b[orderBy]){
        return -1;
      } else if (a[orderBy] > b[orderBy]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;   
      }
    });
  }
  return items;
}
```

The right product need to show when it has the same "tag" like the filter tag.

Answer (score 0):

because p doesn't exist out of

```
<select>
 <option *ngFor="let p of PriceFilter">{{p.DisplayText}}</option>
</select>
```

to catch it in your next ngfor filter. You have to find an alternative to get the value of user selected p and pass it to your filter pipe.

**Edited as you provided in the comment**

```
<h2>store</h2>
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name=Gender>
  <option *ngFor="let g of GenderFilter">{{g.DisplayText}}</option> 
 </select>
 <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOptionPrice" name=Price>
  <option *ngFor="let p of PriceFilter">{{p.DisplayText}}</option> 
 </select>
```

you can actually separate the filter from ngfor. separate ngFor in an ng-container and call your filter function in your tr tag.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let P of products | orderBy: 'PriceFilter'">
 <tr *ngIf=filter(selectedOptionPrice)>
  <td>{{selectedOptionPrice.DisplayText}}</td>
 </tr>
</ng-container>
```

add your filter pipe as a filter() function your .ts file. This will be more specific than using a pipe.

**.TS file**

```
filter(price) {
 return price 
    ? this.items.filter(item => item.ProductTags.indexOf(price) !== -1) : this.items;
}
```

Comment: changed it and again, can't bind: <h2>store</h2>
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption" name=Gender>
  <option *ngFor="let g of GenderFilter">{{g.DisplayText}}</option>
</select>
<select>
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOptionPrice" name=Price>
  <option *ngFor="let p of PriceFilter">{{p.DisplayText}}</option>
</select>